# How do I create radial heatmap in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am able to get the radial heatmap in ggplot2 like this[image]

How do I get the same using matplotlib?

This is a sample df and visualisation, not the data used to create the radial heatmap using ggplot2.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (24,12)))
df.columns = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
sns.heatmap(df, cmap = "coolwarm", cbar = False)
```

EDIT: My data's dimension is the same as the sample df I have provided. I would like to plot the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

n = 12
m = 24
rad = np.linspace(0, 10, m)
a = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
r, th = np.meshgrid(rad, a)

z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (n,m))
plt.subplot(projection="polar")

plt.pcolormesh(th, r, z, cmap = 'inferno')

plt.plot(a, r, ls='none', color = 'k') 
plt.grid()
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('a.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: U R welcome. Happy to help. Dimensions are really important in python

Comment: Just something minor, the remaining part of editing the plot - labels, axis ticks, etc, - are the same as every other matplotlib plots right?

Comment: Yes, Feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

I would use polar.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

n= 12
rad = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
a = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
r, th = np.meshgrid(rad, a)

z = np.random.rand(n,n)
plt.subplot(projection="polar")

plt.pcolormesh(th, r, z)

plt.plot(a, r, color='k', ls='none',cmap = 'binary') 
plt.grid()
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your code? Can you illustrate the same thing with the sample dataframe I have provided?

Comment: Sure.  first, you need three variables. radial(rad),angular (a) and the heat (z) value. I made 100 variables in for rad and a. then I used np.mesh to put them in mesh grid and finally I added the heat value as a random variable.

Comment: you can also change the color and add a color bar.

Comment: Can you see the image
?

Comment: I can see the image. Can you replicate it using my dataframe? I tried with the same code by substituting `z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (24,12))` but it didn't work.

Comment: It should have the same dimension as rad and a (n*n)
z = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (n,n))

Comment: So then I guess I can't plot my graph using your answer with my specifications(?)

Comment: why not? just use 12 and 24 but do not forget about the order. If you received an Error please write it.

Comment: Same code as yours, except for z I gave `z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (24,12))` and got `TypeError: Dimensions of C (24, 12) are incompatible with X (12) and/or Y (12); see help(pcolormesh)`

Comment: you should do:
     z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (12,24))

Comment: `TypeError: Dimensions of C (12, 24) are incompatible with X (12) and/or Y (12); see help(pcolormesh)` Same error again

Comment: try to run my new answer first. Then change it one line at the time