# Create a perceptual map with Matplotlib or Seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, data-analysis

Hi everyone: i'm doing some research on vowel sounds, and I'm referring to an article, and i want to recreate something like this:
[image]

I basically want to recreate these perceptual maps and scatter plots. These are my data:

```
frequency,gender,vowel,predicted_vowel,sex,age
206.2,3.0,1.8,2,M,20
150.4,1.0,2.4,1,M,20
728.8,1.0,3.4,1,M,20
387.6,4.0,3.6,4,M,20
728.8,3.0,3.2,1,M,20
206.2,2.0,3.2,3,M,20
728.8,2.0,2.6,1,M,20
206.2,0.0,3.4,3,M,20
999.4,1.0,4.4,0,M,20
531.5,4.0,3.4,1,M,20
728.8,3.0,2.2,3,M,20
728.8,3.0,1.4,3,M,20
387.6,2.0,2.6,4,M,20
206.2,0.0,2.8,3,M,20
282.7,1.0,3.2,4,M,20
728.8,3.0,0.6,3,M,20
80.0,4.0,1.8,2,M,20
282.7,3.0,0.4,1,M,20
109.7,3.0,0.6,1,M,20
531.5,0.0,4.0,3,M,20
```

frequency, gender and vowel belong to the sample, predicted_vowel is instead the vowel predicted by the subject, and then age and sex of the subject.

Thanks everyone.

EDIT for @JohanC
Here's a portion of the article:

For the presentation of the experimental results, we devised a visual 
representation of perceived vowels.Results are grouped based on the pitch:
(1)low (80hz-306hz),
(2) medium(307hz612hz), 
(3) high (613hz-1000hz).

We first used scatter plots to show the entire distribution of data samples(Figure 3d–3f).To provide a sort of multisensory unification, we also mapped the data samples to a set of perceptual maps (Figure 3a–3c).

For each pitch group a perceptual map was generated by partitioning a circle into 24 sectors of 15° and five circular crowns, one for each vowel. Every tile is color-coded and represents how the corresponding sound in the VTP space is perceived.The hue indicates the label(A, E, I, O, U) chosen by the majority of participants listening to that sound (see legend in Figure 3).The saturation indicates the level of agreement.For example, if a given sound was listened by ten participants,with seven assigning the label A and three assigning the label E,then the corresponding tile would be colored in red,with saturation value of 0.7, indicating that the most perceived vowel was A with 70% of agreement.

Instead of using those pitches, I have to use the following:

(1) Low: 80 - 186, 
(2) Medium:  186 - 431, 
(3) High:  431 - 1000

Comment: You see to be referring to a radial heatmap as in e.g. [How do I create radial heatmap in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087868/how-do-i-create-radial-heatmap-in-matplotlib).  Without an explanation what the angles, the radial distances and the colors are supposed to mean, your question seems hard to tackle.

Comment: I think that the colors refer to the vowels predicted by the subjects, while as regards its sections there are 5, that is the vowels

Comment: I have a portion of the article, but i don't know how to move the discussion into the chat @JohanC

Comment: This is all very weird and confusing.  5 concentric circles for 5 vowels, but no indication which is which.  And why does the vowel in the center gets much less area than the one at the edge? Wouldn't a rectangular chart be more appropriate? The frequencies go around the circle, but there is no indication where it starts. The color, is that the vowel understood by the listener, or the one intended by the speaker, or the "predicted" one. About the columns, e.g. the first row `gender:3.0,vowel:1.8,predicted_vowel:2` is hard to make sense of. Why do `I` and `O` have very similar colors?

Comment: Because they are near, in fact: [A,E,I,O,U], the I is next to O

Comment: Uhm yes, but my main problem is how to recreate the perceptual map, i'll take care of the data

Comment: You might want to come back when you have some real test data and are able to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it is now, there are too many unknowns, an answer would be an unwieldy list of possibilities.