# Radial heatmap from similarity matrix in Python

Tags: python, plot, large-data, holoviews

### Summary

I have a 2880x2880 similarity matrix (8.5 mil points). My attempt with Holoviews resulted in a 500 MB HTML file which never finishes "opening". So how do I make a round heatmap of the matrix?

### Details

I had data from 10 different places, measured over 1 whole year. The hours of each month were turned into arrays, so each month had 24 arrays (one for all 00:00, one for all 01:00 ... 22:00, 23:00).

These were about 28-31 cells long, and each cell had the measurement of the thing I'm trying to analyze. So there are these 24 arrays for each month of 1 whole year, i.e. 24x12 = 288 arrays per place. And there are measurements from 10 places. So a total of 2880 arrays were created and all compared to each other, and saved in a 2880x2880 matrix with similarity coefficients.

I'm trying to turn it into a radial similarity matrix like the one from [holoviews](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/RadialHeatMap.html), but without the ticks and tags (since the format *Place01Jan0800* would be cumbersome to look at for 2880 rows), just the shape and colors and divisions:
[image]

I managed to create the HTML file itself, but it ended up being 500 MB big, so it never shows up when I open it up. It's just blank. I've added a minimal example below of what I have, and replaced the loading of the datafile with some randomly generated data.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
from bokeh.plotting import show
import gc

# Function creating dummy data for this example
def transformer():
    dimension = 2880
    dummy_matrix = ([[ random.random() for i in range(dimension)  ] for j in range(dimension)]) #Fake, similar data

    col_vals = [str(i) for i in range(dimension*dimension)] # Placeholder
    row_vals = [str(i) for i in range(dimension*dimension)] # Placeholder
    val_vals = (np.reshape(np.array(dummy_matrix), -1)).tolist() # Turn matrix into an array
    idx_vals = [i for i in range(dimension*dimension)] # Placeholder

    return idx_vals, val_vals, row_vals, col_vals

idx_arr, val_arr, row_arr, col_arr = transformer()
df = pd.DataFrame({"values": val_arr, "x-label": row_arr, "y-label": col_arr}, index=idx_arr)

hv.extension('bokeh')
heatmap = hv.HeatMap(df, ["x-label", "y-label"])
heatmap.opts(opts.HeatMap(cmap="viridis", radial=True))

gc.collect() # Attempt to save memory, because this thing is huge
show(hv.render(heatmap))
```

I had a look at [datashader](https://datashader.org/user_guide/Grids.html) to see if it would help, but I have no idea how to plug it in (if it's possible for this case) to this radial heatmap, since it seems like the radial heatmap doesn't have that datashade-feature.

So I have no idea how to tackle this. I would be content with a broad overview too, I don't need the details nor the hover-infobox nor ability to zoom or any fancy extra features, I just need the general overview for a presentation. I'm open to any solution really.

Comment: Why do you want to use a RadialHeatMap? As stated in the document, "A radial HeatMap is well suited to discover periodic patterns and trends in time series data and other cyclic variables.". I think it is reasonable to use RadialHeatMap to plot the orginal 288 * 10 data without computing similarity. If you want to visualize the "similarity matrix" , I think perhaps you can just map the similarity matrix to a 2880 * 2880 image using a color map.

Comment: The reason for the heatmap is that I want to show under which months or hours the "measurement spikes" pool, the heatmap has clear divisions so people can see where the measurements of January begins and ends for example. But I don't necessarily have to use a heatmap, I would absolutely accept a color map as a solution/answer as well, I could probably add some kind of ticks manually to it. I'm very short on time unfortunately, and I have no idea how to construct the color map from the 2880x2880 `dummy_matrix`-object. If you could show me how to do it, I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: If you want to see  "under which months or hours the measurement spikes pool", you can just plot the original 288*10 data matrix. There will be a cluster of deeper color(assuming the deeper the color is, the larger the measurement is) in the plotted heatmap. Visualizing the similarity matrix `M` does not make sense. For example, `M[i][j]` will be large when both data[i] and data[j] are very small (not only when data[i] and data[j] are both "measurement spike"). Also, elements on the diagonal of the similarity matrix is always the largest sine `data[i]=data[i]`, perhaps not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use heatmp instead of radial heatamp for showing the similarity matrix. The reasons are:

1. The radial heatmap is designed for periodic variable. The time varible(288 hours) can be considered to be periodic data, however, I think the 288*10(288 hours, 10 places) is no longer periodic because of the existence of the "place".
2. Near the center of the radial heatmap, the color points will be too dense to be understood by the human.

The following is a simple code to show a heatmap.

```
import matplotlib.cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import numpy as np

n = 2880
m = 2880
dummy_matrix = np.random.rand(m, n)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50,50))  # change the figsize to control the resolution
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap("Blues")  # you may use other build-in colormap or define you own colormap
# if your data is not in range[0,1], use a normalization. Here is normalized by min and max values.
norm = Normalize(vmin=np.amin(dummy_matrix), vmax=np.amax(dummy_matrix))
image = ax.imshow(dummy_matrix, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(image)

plt.show()
```

Which gives:
[image: This result]

Another idea that comes to me is that, perhaps the computation of similarity matrix is unnecessary, and you can plot the orginial 288 * 10 data using radial heat map or just a normal heatmap, and one can get to know the data similarity from the color distribution directly.

Comment: I had to think it through for a moment. 288 * 10 sounded a little counterintuitive, but as I remembered that the rows are all just the same thing stapled ontop of each other, it makes more sense now. But just to make sure I thought it through correctly; so for instance cell [50,67] has a counterpart/exact replica inside of the row [0...2880,0]? I wouldn't be missing showing anything? (Also, very helpful answer! Thanks!)

Comment: @user326964 What do you mean by cell [50,67]? it seems that it is outside the index range of the 288*10 matrix `Data`. If `Data[10, 0]` is very close to `Data[286, 10]`, they will have similar color, however, they may be far from each other spatially on the heatmap. I think human can recognize their colors' similarity despite the distance between them. Is this what you want?

Comment: If you imagine that we divide the square heatmap diagonally - the bottom half will be a mirror image of the upper half (each point in the lower has an identical twin in the upper). So we can throw away half of the heatmap. But can we throw away more than that and keep all unique representations? So for example a comparison between place A and B is the same as comparing B and A, so we can throw one of them away because we have the information in the other. If we throw all except 1 row away, will all of the comparisons be inside of that row?

Comment: @user326964 You may misunderstand what I mean. I think you'd better draw a heatmap of the **original data** matrix the size of which is 288 by 10. You have 288*10 **original** datapoint  **without computing similairy**, each data point cooresponds to one element in the matrix, and one pixel in the heatmap(the color is related to the scale of the data of this point). In a word, you just plot the original data, and the similarity can be figured out by the viewer of the heatmap. **If you plot as I suggested, no "comparision info" is stored in the heatmap and should be find by the viewer.**

Comment: If you plot 288*10, you find similarity by watch the heatmap and find "which two points have similar color". If in a certain hour, the data is nearly same for all place, you will find a "strip" at the x coordinate of this hour. If you plot 2880*2880, you can find similarity by finding "which points have deeper color" and then find the cooresponding two datapoints using the x,y coordinates. If in a certain hour, the data is nearly same for all place, there are just several seperate points with deep color, and it's hard for human to recognize a pattern(But may be easy for computer to process).

Comment: I think it is not possible to figure out "similarity pattern" from the visualization of similarity matrix. However, you can figure out "how similar two points are" for any two points. I think perhaps you need to show the pattern("under which months or hours the measurement spikes pool" as you commented before), so I will recommend not to use "similarity matrix".

Comment: Aha you mean like that. Yes, that would have worked if my measured data was point-by-point originally. But I should have mentioned that it is time series, and they don't have one-value representations from the beginning. The similarity comparison computation creates those one-value representations saying "this pair is so-and-so similar to each other". So I have to use the similarity values.

Comment: @user326964 If so, perhpas you can do a PCA  analysis (take the first 3 componet) or use t-SNE algorithm to map the origimal data to 3-dimensional space, then map them to RGB values. In this way you can also map the original datapoint to RGB value. I think by looking at the "similarity matrix", you can not find a  "similarity pattern" you want. Perhaps a dimensionality reduction algorithm is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Plain Matplotlib seems to be able to handle it, based on answers from here: [How do I create radial heatmap in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087868/how-do-i-create-radial-heatmap-in-matplotlib)

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

n = 2880
m = 2880
rad = np.linspace(0, 10, m)
a = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
r, th = np.meshgrid(rad, a)

dummy_matrix = ([[ random.random() for i in range(n)  ] for j in range(m)])

plt.subplot(projection="polar")

plt.pcolormesh(th, r, dummy_matrix, cmap = 'Blues')

plt.plot(a, r, ls='none', color = 'k')
plt.grid()
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig("custom_radial_heatmap.png")
plt.show()
```

And it didn't even take an eternity, took only about 20 seconds max.
You would think it would turn out monstrous like that

[image]

But the sheer amount of points drowns out the jaggedness, WOOHOO!

[image]

There's some things left to be desired, like tags and ticks, but I think I'll figure that out.